# Как удалить пунктуацию из строки Юникода?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, unicode

Например, есть строка на японском, китайском, русском и вообще каком-нибудь языке. Я пытаюсь удалить оттуда все символы пунктуации, заменив их пробелами при помощи регулярного выражения. Но пунктуация не заменяется. Как это сделать?

Пробую так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

delete = re.compile(ur'\p{P}', re.UNICODE)
test = u"Пунктуация: ,.!?"

print delete.sub(' ', test)
```

Получаю

> `$ python test.py 
> Пунктуация: ,.!?`

`\p{P}` - это, по идее, любой символ пунктуации.

Comment: см. примеры кода: [Remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Вот твоя регулярка:

```
re.compile(u'\W+?', re.UNICODE)
```

Прочитать что значит, можно [тут](http://www.intuit.ru/department/pl/python/6/4.html).

Comment: `\W` убирает больше чем нужно, не только пунктуацию, например,  `re.sub(u'\W', 'wrong', u'\N{EURO SIGN}')`. Можно использовать [`regex` модуль, который понимает  `u'\p{P}'` или `unicode.translate()` с ипользованием unicodedata.category](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279)